# How to use an azure ad b2c sign in policy on web app start up?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I have set up an azure ad b2c tenant and created a sign in policy which uses a bespoke webpage (web page is stored and accessed in azure blob storage). I have integrated the ad into a MVC web application. I would like to be able to invoke the sign in policy when someone tries to access the application, but instead I am prompted with Microsofts default office 365 sign in page. this does work however I would like the sign in page to be the bespoke one which I have created. how do i integrate the sign in policy in this way?

Answer (score 0):

First please ensure that you have enabled the page UI customization for the policy you are using in MVC application. You can check it on the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) like below:
[image]

Then please ensure that the **custom page URL** is available to access, you can verify it through the browser.

More detail about page user interface (UI) customization feature for Azure B2C tenant, you can refer links below:

[Azure Active Directory B2C: A helper tool used to demonstrate the page user interface (UI) customization feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization-helper-tool)

[Azure Active Directory B2C: Customize the Azure AD B2C user interface (UI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization)

Comment: This only works if you have been allowed to enter the site and then login, my problem is that i would like to login before accessing the site, and use a custom webpage. The webpage itself is stored in blob storage in azure which means it is accessable

Comment: What did you mean login before accessing the site? Based on my understanding, we could force users login-in before they access the site by protect the whole web site. For example, in an MVC web application, we can protect all the controllers, so that when users try to access the web application, it will redirect to the custom page we config for the policy correctly. Please feel free to let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: you are correct, but when you do this it will prompt the deafult microsoft login page (office 365 login page which you can only add company branding to). i would like to be able to change this page to my custom page

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. The web app will redirect to the custom page works when I run this project( need to protect the home controller). Please ensure that you didn't enable **Authentication/Authorization** ( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication)) at the portal.  And I am using [this code sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet.git) and customize the login page for the sign-in policy.